# Add programatically a text swatch option attribute

Tags: attributes, magento-2.1, swatches

I can use the method addAttributeOption() from Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup to add options to a dropdown attribute, something like this:

```
$this->getCategorySetup()->addAttributeOption(
    [
        'attribute_id'  => $this->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getAttributeId(),
        'order'         => [0],
        'value'         => [
            [
                0 => $label
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Now, how can I add an attribute option to a text swatch, including its swatch label?

Using Magento 2.1

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?